# How to create drop-down submenu using data-ng-repeat in angularjs ??

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to create drop-down menu/submenu using data-ng-repeat in angularjs. where one ng-repeat used in ul and other ng-repeat is using in li submenu  and associate it with related data.

Comment: Got any code for us to review?

Comment: TBH you can do it exactly how you described, though a recursive template would probably be best. If you have any problems with implementing it show us your code and maybe we can help